# Paging failed to find any result when I used Pageable

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my repository

```
public interface OperateLogRepository extends JpaRepository<OperateLog, Long> {

  Page<OperateLog> findByBelongTypeAndBelongId(Integer belongType, Long belongId, Pageable pageable);
}
```

And this is my service

```
public PageResp<OperateLogResp> findOperateLog(UserWrapper userWrapper, PageReq pageReq) {
Page<OperateLog> pageResult = logRepository
    .findByBelongTypeAndBelongId(userWrapper.getBelongTypeCode(), userWrapper.getBelongId(),
        new PageRequest(pageReq.getPage() - 1, pageReq.getSize(), Direction.DESC, "id"));
return PageResp.from(pageResult.map(OperateLogResp::from), pageReq);
```

}

However, I can not get any result from this query.

And I try print the sql, the sql like this:

```
selectas [all fields] from t_operate_log operatelog0_ where 
operatelog0_.f_belong_type=? and operatelog0_.f_belong_id=? order by operatelog0_.f_id desc limit ?
```

This **sql** is work for me,

But, the hibernate bind parameter:

```
binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

The third parameter for **limit** is missing.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Pageable instead of PageRequest:

just 
`Pageable p = new PageRequest(pageReq.getPage() - 1, pageReq.getSize(), Direction.DESC, "id");`

and then

```
Page<OperateLog> pageResult = logRepository
    .findByBelongTypeAndBelongId(userWrapper.getBelongTypeCode(), userWrapper.getBelongId(), p);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. My error is datasource select error. I activated the wrong environment, there is no data in this environment